# How "history" object is getting evaluated in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Trying to understand the below three,

1. Why "history" has been put inside curly braces?
2. Why "props" has NOT been put inside curly braces?
3. Why "...props" has been used.Or I mean why we are spreading the
   `props` object here.

A little bit about the first point - Per my understanding "{history}" means a javascript object which should be evaluated but I could not see that this object has not been initialized in the component where the below code for  is written.

```
<Route exact path="/add" render={({history}, props) => <AddSubscriber history={history} {...props} addSubscriberHandler={this.addSubscriberHandler} />} />
```

Answer (score 2):

Pleaser find below the answers of your questions using the following block of code:

```
<Route exact path="/add" render={({history}, props) => <AddSubscriber history={history} {...props} addSubscriberHandler={this.addSubscriberHandler} />} />*
```

1. In the above code, if you use curly braces over history, it simply means you are destructuring history variable from the props, you can also use props.history both are the same thing.
2. props are not in curly braces because props are the objects passed to that function,  we can destructure any key of the object using curly braces.
3. "..." is called spread operator, this is used if you want to destructure your object and pass all the values of the object.

Comment: So , we have the history and props variables in two places- as the function arguments and as the attributes of AddSubcriber component. So the same meaning in both the places?.And why we need those in two places. Any idea?

Comment: Additional parameter?. Can you give a sample for this?

Comment: @user3742125 please mark this answer as accepted if that solves your current problem if you have further concerns you can raise a different question. Thanks

Comment: I replaced the above code as below as you mentioned. But I am getting error saying "Cannot read property 'history' of undefined".
<Route exact path="/add" render={({history}, props) => <AddSubscriber history = {props.history} addSubscriberHandler={this.addSubscriberHandler} />} />